# Paypal REST API Multiple Buttons on a Page

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment, paypal-rest-sdk

I am having an issue implementing multiple PayPal Express Checkout buttons on a single page using the REST API. This is a video purchasing site where the users will only purchase single videos so there is no need for a shopping cart that keeps track of multiple items. I simply want to list the available videos, and then display a PayPal Buy Now button next to each one. I have a loop that is pulling the video information content from my database but I can't seem to figure out why the buttons won't work.

I keep getting an error in the console stating

> Error: Document is ready and element #ws_lifh1 does not exist↵    at
>   https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:7798:54↵

ws_lifh1 is the video id for each video. I get this error 4 times but each shows its proper video id in the error.

[Here is an image of the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJfjG.png)

Here is my code that generates this

```js
var ppbutton = paypal.Button.render( {

env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox',

client: {
 sandbox: 'something',
 production: 'something'
},

commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

style: {
 label: 'buynow',
 branding: 'true',
 size: 'small', // small | medium | large | responsive
 shape: 'rect', // pill | rect
 color: 'blue' // gold | blue | silver | black
},

payment: function ( data, actions ) {
 return actions.payment.create( {
  payment: {
   transactions: [ {
    amount: {
     total: '12.95',
     currency: 'USD'
},

description: 'Video purchase from Boomer Fitness with Michael G.',
 item_list: {
  items: [ {
   name: 'Lean in Fifteen at Home #1',
   videoid: 'ws_lifh1',
   price: '12.95',
   currency: 'USD'
      } ]
  }
 } ]
 }
} );
},

onAuthorize: function ( data, actions ) {
 return actions.payment.execute().then( function ( payment ) {
  window.alert( 'payment received' );
  } );
},

onCancel: function ( data, actions ) {
  /* 
 * Buyer cancelled the payment 
 */
},

onError: function ( err ) {
 /* 
 * An error occurred during the transaction 
 */
 }
}, '#' + videoid );

var videolisting = document.createElement( 'div' );
videolisting.setAttribute( 'class', 'row bottom-margin' );
videolisting.innerHTML = "<div class='col-md-12'><h3>" + videoname + "</h3><h3>$ " + videoprice + "</h3><div id='" + videoid + "'></div>" + ppbutton + "</div></div>";
document.getElementById( 'container' ).appendChild( videolisting );
} );
```

Comment: If you want an answer, makeup the whitespace of your code so it's readable.

Comment: Done. Though it shows differently than it does when editing it.

Comment: Having a similar issue. Damn, 2 years ago. Is this still not answered?